# mkdir with date name?

Tags: command-line, date, mkdir

In Linux shell, am I able to create a directory but the name would be a string returned from another program? And if I am able, how to?

In particular I am asked to create a new directory in my Home, and its name would be the minute on my computer's clock. Let's suppose `/home/john/01/`, `01` is the minutes on my clock.

I was thinking something like pipeline `date +"%M" | mkdir` but I do not know how I am gonna put that returned number into the `mkdir` program.

Finally another idea came to my mind, something like this `mkdir (date +"%M")` but this as well is a mistake. Any help please?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The concept you're looking for is [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution), which uses the syntax `$(command)`

```
mkdir /home/john/$(date +%M)
```

You may also see the older 'backtick' syntax, `` `command` ``

Comment: another way could be piping the output of date command into a mkdir command with xargs

`date +%M | xargs mkdir`

Answer (score 22):

`mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d)` or I personally use `mkdir $(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)` for hh:mm:ss. `date --help` will give you the different formats if you need something more.

Comment: This is the correct answer imo because it has the layout of yyymmdd etc.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it easily using following command:

```
$ min=$(date +"+%M"); mkdir $min
```

Comment: Also a nice way, good to know that you can declare a variable and then give that value to mkdir program, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do that by typing the following command:

```
mkdir ~/$(date | awk -F':' '{print $2}')
```

The command creates a directory in `home` folder and gives the current minute as name.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  that way works as well but its a little bit complicated for me!!